# Build a LINQ to SQL Group By Property Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression

I'm trying to use GroupBy dynamically and I know this is a big no-no with LINQ to SQL, but I think this could possibly work. I just need some assistance with the expression syntax.

Take this trivial example:

```
var grouped = from c in ctx.Customers
              group c by c.LastName into Group
              select Group;
```

I'd like to be able to group by first name OR last name, depending on the user's preference. Now I understand that LINQ must build a SQL compatible expression here, but I just want to swap out the property that it'll use to build the final SQL command.

So I've been experimenting with stuff like:

```
private Expression<Func<Customer, TKey>> GetColumn<TKey>(Customer c, 
  GroupingType g)
{
    if(g == GroupingType.First)
        var e = Expression<Func<Customer, string>> l = () => c.FirstName; //Here
    // etc...
}

var groupingType = GroupingType.First;

var grouped = from c in ctx.Customers
              group c by GetColumn<string>(c, groupingType) into Group
              select Group;
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction before I get lost in a sea of expressions and invokes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool byLastName = true;

Expression<Func<Customer, string>> exp;

if (byLastName)
{
    exp = p => p.LastName;
}
else
{
    exp = p => p.FirstName;
}

var grouped = ctx.Customers.GroupBy(exp);
```

Sometimes the functional syntax of LINQ is easier to use than the `from... select...` syntax. Here the use of the `Expression<Func<Customer, string>>` is explicit.